# How to show the id of each div individually inside them?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing an HTML+JS page, that file has bunch of divs which containing a `id` individually, in the format of `YYYYMMDD`, just like `20230307`, `20230308`, `20230309`, etc.

```
<div id='20230307'>
    <span>20230307</span>
    <div>some text...<br>...<hr>...</div>
</div>
<div id='20230308'>
    <span>20230308</span>
    <div>some text...<br>...<hr>...</div>
</div>
```

However I get a lot of divs. Without making the HTML code so long, how can I use javascript to show the id of the div instead of typing text inside the tag `<span>...</span>`?

is there something like ...

```
<script>
    function getDiv_id(){document.write(DIV.id);}
</script>

<span>
    <script>getDiv_id();</script>
</span>
```

Here is what i have tried :

```
<div id='20230307'>
    <script>
        document.getElementById(this).innerHTML=document.getElementById(id);
        document.write.innerHTML=document.getElementById(this);
        document.write=document.getElementById(this);
        document.write=document.getElementById(this.id);
        document.write=document.getElementById(id);
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: What code have you tried?  It's easy to generate repetitive HTML with Javascript.

Comment: <div id='20230307'>20230307
<script>
document.getElementById(this).innerHTML=document.getElementById(id);
document.write.innerHTML=document.getElementById(this);
document.write=document.getElementById(this);
document.write=document.getElementById(this.id);
document.write=document.getElementById(id);
</script>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select first `span` in each block by `d.getElementsByTagName('span').[0]`.

Select `id` value of each block by `d.id`.

Use `forEach` to add `innerHTML`.

```js
const blocks = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
Array.prototype.filter.call(blocks, d => d.hasAttribute('id')).forEach(d => d.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = d.id)
```

```html
<div id='20230307'><br>
  <span></span><br>
  <div>some text...<br>...
    <hr>...
  </div><br>
</div>
<div id='20230308'><br>
  <span></span><br>
  <div>some text...<br>...
    <hr>...
  </div><br>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean adding the code like this way ... ?

```
<script>
const blocks = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
Array.prototype.filter.call(blocks, d => d.hasAttribute('id')).forEach(d => d.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = d.id)
</script>
```

why my page shows only 'some text'  ...

Comment: Yes, wrap the js code by `<script>` and add it at the bottom of page.

Comment: If you add js code before page content, `document.getElementsBy...` will get nothing beacause js code was executed before page content loaded.